# scapy bad file descriptor

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

[scapy OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380130/scapy-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor)
same error as this guy . using python 2.7.5 on windows.downloded all the extentions and followed everything step by step. still doesnt seem to work. every function i try wheter it's sr1 or send or anything else i get this error OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor..
and it mentiones lines in some of the scapy scripts (scapy\sendrecv.pyc as example..)
the simplest things i try running in the interpreter doesnt work. as in :

```
from scapy.all import * 
p=sr1(IP(dst='190.200.2.5')/ICMP())
```

so i tried reinstalling this time everything according to the guide they provide int the website and using python 2.6 , same results ..

```
>>> p=sr1(IP(dst='192.168.1.1')/ICMP())
ERROR: --- Error sending packets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 374, in sndrcv
    pks.send(p)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 237, in send
    ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
  File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
OSError: Result too large

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    p=sr1(IP(dst='192.168.1.1')/ICMP())
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 335, in sr1
    a,b=sndrcv(s,x,*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 431, in sndrcv
    os.write(1, ".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Please attach your source code. Does invoking some of `scapy`'s functions directly from the interpreter work?

Comment: the simplest thing doesnt work as in :
from scapy.all import *
p=sr1(IP(dst="190.200.2.5')/ICMP())
it's in closed lan network.

Comment: Was this executed from the interpreter? If so, please edit your question to show the invocation and its entire exception log.

Comment: added source and exception log....

Comment: The first error seems to be a [`libdnet` issue on windows 7 with wireless interfaces](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/issue/373/libdnet-issue-on-windows-7-with-wireless). Can you try this on a wired interface perhaps?

Comment: yes i can , the first error is not what censorns me , the second one is what keeping poping up no matter what i try...

Comment: If this works on a wired interface, the second error might be a different manifestation of the first one.

Comment: u can just ignore the first error i tried again in a wireless network and that's why that first error occoured ,it doesnt work for me in a wired one as well . 
no matter what i change it doesnt work!

Comment: Look at the answer I gave on the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380130/scapy-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor) Did you use IDLE or execute it via a command prompt/shell?